# Fast way to check if a number is evenly divisible by another?

Tags: vb.net, numbers, integer, division

I was wondering what the fastest way is to check for divisibility in VB.NET.

I tried the following two functions, but I feel as if there are more efficient techniques.

```
Function isDivisible(x As Integer, d As Integer) As Boolean
     Return Math.floor(x / d) = x / d
End Function
```

Another one I came up with:

```
Function isDivisible(x As Integer, d As Integer) As Boolean
     Dim v = x / d
     Dim w As Integer = v
     Return v = w
End Function
```

Is this a more practical way?

Comment: The second one seems pretty efficient as long as it works and should be enough for the JIT to inline it automatically

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `Mod`:

```
Function isDivisible(x As Integer, d As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (x Mod d) = 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 8):

Use 'Mod' which returns the remainder of number1 divided by number2.  So if remainder is zero then number1 is divisible by number2.

e.g.

Dim result As Integer = 10 Mod 5 ' result = 0

Answer (score 4):

use the [mod operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)